# How can i update a method inside Update only if the value of array has changed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Inside the Update:

```
private void Update()
    {
        GeneratePatrolPoints();
    }
```

And the GeneratePatrolPoint:

```
public GameObject[] GeneratePatrolPoints()
    {
        GameObject[] TeleportationBooths = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Teleportation Booth");
        patrolPoints = new PatrolData[TeleportationBooths.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < patrolPoints.Length; i++)
        {
            patrolPoints[i] = new PatrolData();
            patrolPoints[i].target = TeleportationBooths[i].transform;
            patrolPoints[i].minDistance = 30f;
            patrolPoints[i].lingerDuration = 3f;
            patrolPoints[i].desiredHeight = 20f;
            patrolPoints[i].flightSmoothTime = 10f;
            patrolPoints[i].maxFlightspeed = 10f;
            patrolPoints[i].flightAcceleration = 3f;
            patrolPoints[i].levelingSmoothTime = 0.5f;
            patrolPoints[i].maxLevelingSpeed = 10000f;
            patrolPoints[i].levelingAcceleration = 2f;
        }
        return TeleportationBooths;
    }
```

I want to make that only if the length of the array TeleportationBooths has changed then call GeneratePatrolPoint in the Update again.

For example if TeleportationBooths length was first time 5 and then in the Update if it was changed and now it's 7 or 70 each time if the length has changed from the last number then update it.

Comment: You should avoid using `FindGameObjectsWithTag`, instead pass the list through the arguments in the function. This also allows you to check if the length of the list has changed before even calling the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TeleportationBooths` is an array therefore its length **cannot** change. It's also a local variable and therefore **cannot** be used anywhere else except inside that `GeneratePatrolPoints()` function.

Here are the list of things you need to do:

**1**.Make `TeleportationBooths` a `List` instead of an array.

**2**.Make it a global variable.

**3**.For the size of `TeleportationBooths` to change, you have to call `TeleportationBooths.Add` to add Object or `TeleportationBooths.Remove` to remove Object or  `TeleportationBooths.Clear();` to remove everything from that list. That's the only way to make `TeleportationBooths.Count` change.

**4**.You can then use `TeleportationBooths.Count` to check if the variable changed over time.

Something like this:

```
List<GameObject> TeleportationBooths = new List<GameObject>();
int oldLength;

void Start()
{
    GameObject[] tempObj = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Teleportation Booth");
    for (int i = 0; i < tempObj.Length; i++)
    {
        //Add to list only if it does not exist
        if (!TeleportationBooths.Contains(tempObj[i]))
        {
            TeleportationBooths.Add(tempObj[i]);
        }
    }

    //Get the current Size
    if (tempObj != null)
    {
        oldLength = tempObj.Length;
    }
}

void Update()
{
    //Check if oldLength has changed
    if (oldLength != TeleportationBooths.Count)
    {
        //Update oldLength
        oldLength = TeleportationBooths.Count;

        //Call your the function
        GeneratePatrolPoints();
    }
}
```

To change the List, call `TeleportationBooths.Add(objToAdd)`, 
 `TeleportationBooths.Remove(objToRemove);` or `TeleportationBooths.Clear()` from somewhere depending on if you want to add, remove or clear the `List`.

**NOTE**:

Do **not** call `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Teleportation Booth");` every frame in the Update function. If you Instantiate a new GameObject with the *"Teleportation Booth"* tag during tun-time, just add it to the `TeleportationBooths` List. If you want to destroy it, just remove it from the `List` first then destroy it. That's the logic here.

Comment: How can i call the List from another script if the scripts not on same gameobject ? I have a script of a ui button and there when i click the button i decide if to destroy(and create new objects) or only to add new objects and there i need also to update the list if destroy to Clear the list if to add so to add new item. But how can i get access to the list ? If both scripts was on the same gameobject i could use getcomponent. But i can't put both scripts on same gameobject.

Comment: Hi, make`TeleportationBooths` a `public` variable then use GameObject.Find to the Object this script is attached to then perform `GetComponent` to find this script. You should have known this by now from my other answers on your other account. You can ask new question if you are still confused.

Answer (score 1):

Not a unity expert, but from the C# point of view the only thing you have to do is to create global variable to store array size on the previous step and use it to compare with the new one.

```
    private int oldLength = 0;

    private void Update()
    {
        GameObject[] TeleportationBooths = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Teleportation Booth");
        int newLenght = TeleportationBooths.Length;
        if (newLenght > 0 && newLenght != oldLength)
        {
            GeneratePatrolPoints(TeleportationBooths);
            oldLength = newLenght;
        }
    }

    public GameObject[] GeneratePatrolPoints(GameObject[] TeleportationBooths)
    {
        patrolPoints = new PatrolData[TeleportationBooths.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < patrolPoints.Length; i++)
        {
            patrolPoints[i] = new PatrolData();
            patrolPoints[i].target = TeleportationBooths[i].transform;
            patrolPoints[i].minDistance = 30f;
            patrolPoints[i].lingerDuration = 3f;
            patrolPoints[i].desiredHeight = 20f;
            patrolPoints[i].flightSmoothTime = 10f;
            patrolPoints[i].maxFlightspeed = 10f;
            patrolPoints[i].flightAcceleration = 3f;
            patrolPoints[i].levelingSmoothTime = 0.5f;
            patrolPoints[i].maxLevelingSpeed = 10000f;
            patrolPoints[i].levelingAcceleration = 2f;
        }
        return TeleportationBooths;
    }
```